# Why there are two refs in declaring one-to-many association in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm very new in mongodb, see this [one-to-many example](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

**As per my understanding**

This example says that a person can write many stories or a story `belongs_to` a person , I think storing the `person._id` in stories collection was enough

*why the person collection has the `field` `stories`*

**cases for fetching data**

**case 1**

Fetch all stories of a person whose id is let us say `x`

**solution:** For this just fire a query in story collection `where` `author = x`

**case 2**

Fetch the `author name` of a particular story

**solution**:  For this we have `author` field story collection

Comment: Have a look on this you will get some idea from there [Model One-to-Many Relationships with Embedded Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117832/why-there-are-two-refs-in-declaring-one-to-many-association-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

Put simply: Because there is no such notion as explicit relations in MongoDB.

Mongoose can not know how you want to resolve the relationship. Will the search be from a given story object and the author is to find? Or will the search be to find all stories for an author object? So it makes sure that it can resolve the relation regardless.

Note that there is a problem with that approach, and a **big** one. Say we are not talking of a one-to-few relation as in this example, but a "One-To-A-Shitload"™ relation. Since [BSON documents have a size limit of 16MB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents), you have a limit of relations you can manage this way. Quite some, but there will be an artificial limit.

How to solve this: Instead of using an ODM, do proper modelling yourself. Since you know your use cases. I will give you an example below.

## Detailed

Let us first elaborate your cases a bit:

1. For a **given** user (aka "we already have all the data of that user document"), what are his or her stories?
2. List all stories together with the user name on an overview page.
3. For a selected (**"given"**) story, what are the authors details?
4. And just for demonstration purposes: A **given** user wants to change the name under which a story is displayed, be it his user name or natural name (it happens!) or even pseudonym.

Ok, and now lets put mongoose aside for now and let us think about how we could implement this ourselves. Keeping in mind that

> Data modelling in MongoDB is deriving your model from the questions which come from your use cases so that they most common use cases are covered in the most efficient way.

As opposed to RDBMS modelling, where you identify your entities, their properties and relations and then jump through some hoops to get your questions answered *somehow*.

So, looking at our user stories, I guess we can agree that 2 is the most common use case, 3 and 1 next and 4 is rather rare compared to the other ones.

So now we can start

### Modelling

We model the data involved in our most common use cases first.

So, we want to make the query for stories the most efficient one. And we want to sort the stories in descending order of submission. Simple enough:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId(),
  user: "Name to Display",
  story: "long story cut short",
}
```

Now lets say you want to display your stories, 10 of them:

```
db.stories.find({}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(10)
```

No relation, all the data we need, a single query, used the [default index on `_id`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#default-id-index) for sorting. Since a [timestamp is part of the ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#description) and it is the most significant part, we can use it to sort the stories by time. The question "Hey, but what if one changes his or her user name?" usually comes now. Simple:

```
db.stories.update({"user":oldname},{$set:{"user":newname}},{multi:true})
```

Since this is a rare use case, it only has to be doable and does not have to be extremely efficient. However, later we will see that we have to put an index on `user` anyway.

Talking of authors: Here it really depends on how you want to do it. But I will show you how I tend to model something like that:

```
{
   _id: "username",
   info1: "foo",
   info2: "bar",
   active: true,
   ...
}
```

We make use of some properties of `_id` here: It is a required index with a unique constraint. Just what we want for usernames.

However it comes with a caveat: [`_id` is immutable](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#field-names). So if somebody wants to change his or her username, we need to copy the original user to a document with the `_id` of the new user name and change the user property in our stories accordingly. The advantage of this way of doing it that even when the update for changing usernames (see above) should fail during its runtime, each and every story can still be related to a user. If the update is successful, I tend to log out the user and have him log in with the new username again.

In case you want to have a distinction between username and displayed name, it all becomes even easier:

```
{
  _id: "username",
  displayNames: ["Foo B. Baz","P.S. Eudonym"],
  ...
}
```

Then you use the display name in your stories, of course.

Now let us see how we can get the user details of a given story. We know the author's name so it is as easy as:

```
db.authors.find({"_id":authorNameOfStory})
```

or

```
db.authors.find({"displayNames": authorNameOfStory})
```

Finding all stories for a given user is quite simple, too. It is either:

```
db.stories.find({"name":idFieldOfUser})
```

or

```
db.stories.find({"name":{$in:displayNamesOfUser}})
```

Now we have all your our use cases covered, now we can make them even more efficient with

### Indexing

An obvious index is on the story models `user` field, so we do it:

```
db.stories.ensureIndex({"name":1})
```

If you are good with the "username as `_id`" way only, you are done with indexing. Using display names, you obviously need to index them. Since you most likely want display names and pseudonyms to be unique, it is a bit more complicated:

```
db.authors.ensureIndex({"displayNames":1},{sparse:true, unique:true})
```

Note: We need to make this as [sparse index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/) in order to prevent unnecessary errors when somebody has not decided for a display name or pseudonym yet. Make sure you explicitly *add* this field to an author document only when a user decides for a display name. Otherwise, it would evaluate to `null` server side , which *is* a valid value and you *will* get a constraint violation error, namely "E1100 duplicate key".

## Conclusion

We have covered all your use cases with relations handled by the application thereby simplifying our data model a great deal and have the most efficient queries for our most common use cases. Every use case is covered with a single query, taking into account the information we already have at the time we are doing the query.

Note that there is no artificial limit on how many stories a user can publish since we use implicit relations to our advantage.

As for more complicated queries ("How many stories does each user submit per month?"), use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). That is what it is there for.

Comment: great explanation !!